# I have my own code to create a excel file and I want to send that as an attachment to email without saving file in local system

Tags: apache-poi, jakarta-mail

I am working on a case where I will be supplied with data and I will create a excel file using that data.

Right now I am creating it in my local system and later adding that as an attachment and sending through email using Java Mail Service.

But I dont want to store excel file in my local system and I want to just pass the stream object to email service and send email. So that there wont be any local storage of file still able to send attachment.

Please reply if there is any solution ?

// Created WorkBook
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME)) workbook.write(outputStream);

here FILE_NAME is fully qualified system path where I will be storing file.

I want to skip this and directly send attachment

Comment: So write the workbook to the mail stream instead then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an approach like this and it is working fine:

```
File file = File.createTempFile("Report", "xlsx");
file.deleteOnExit();
Path path = file.toPath();
try (final FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    try (final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        //create your sheets here

        workbook.write(fileOut);
        return Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error during creation of excel report", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (path != null) {
            try {
                Files.delete(path);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Unable to delete file:" + path.toString(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the data to a ByteArrayOutputStream, get the bytes, and use a [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) to supply the data to JavaMail:

```
mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
    new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes,
       "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet =workbook.createSheet(" ");
Font HearderFont=workbook.createFont();
HearderFont.setBold(true);
HearderFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)9);
HearderFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
CellStyle hearderCellStyle=workbook.createCellStyle();
hearderCellStyle.setFont(HearderFont);
//excel file maker
int rownum=1;
for(MailModelClass mailModelonbj:dataStored) {
  Row row=sheet.createRow(rownum++);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(mailModelonbj.(any));
  row.createCell(1).setCellValue(mailModelonbj.(any));
  row.createCell(2).setCellValue(mailModelonbj.(any));
}
```

Comment: When you shared code as answer, please try to explain your code!!!.  You can visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)